# How to get a variable in a closed form given an equation

Tags: real-analysis, closed-form, lambert-w

I need to express a variable in a closed form given an equation, $k^4 = 2^k.$ Taking the logarithm from both sides I get $k^{\frac{1}{k}} = 2^{\frac{1}{4}}$ which is not helping much. I tried other things but without getting a satisfactory solution. Do you have any idea how to get a closed form for $k$ ? Thanks.

Comment: Taking log of both sides gives $4 \log(k) = k \log(2)$ or $\frac{1}{k} \log(k) = \frac{1}{4}\log(2)$  not $k^{1/k} = 2^{1/4}$.

Comment: maybe take a look at lambert W function. Check this link: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+k%5E4%3D2%5Ek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$k^4=2^k$$
$$k^4=e^{\ln(2)k}$$
$$k^4e^{-\ln(2)k}=1$$

We see, your equation is an algebraic equation in dependence of two algebraically independent monomials ($k$, $e^{\ln(2)k}$). Therefore, the [elementary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) $k\to k^4e^{-\ln(2)k}$ doesn't have a [partial inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Partial_inverses) that is an elementary function. Therefore, the equation cannot be *rearranged* for $k$ by applying only elementary functions/operations we can read from the equation.

Your equation is an [exponential polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_polynomial) equation, and some simple cases of such kind of equations can be solved by [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Your equation is solvable by Lambert W:

$$k^4e^{-\ln(2)k}=1$$
$$\left(k^4e^{-\ln(2)k}\right)^\frac{1}{4}=1^\frac{1}{4}$$
$$\left(k^4e^{-\ln(2)k}\right)^\frac{1}{4}=1$$
$$-ke^{-\frac{\ln(2)}{4}k}=1;\ -kie^{-\frac{\ln(2)}{4}k}=1;\ ke^{-\frac{\ln(2)}{4}k}=1;\ kie^{-\frac{\ln(2)}{4}k}=1$$
$\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}$:
$$-\frac{1}{4}\ln(2)k=W_n\left(-\frac{1}{4}\ln(2)\right),\ W_n\left(\frac{1}{4}\ln(2)i\right),\ W_n\left(\frac{1}{4}\ln(2)\right),\ W_n\left(-\frac{1}{4}\ln(2)i\right)$$
$$k=-\frac{4}{\ln(2)}W_n\left(-\frac{1}{4}\ln(2)\right),\ -\frac{4}{\ln(2)}W_n\left(\frac{1}{4}\ln(2)i\right),\ -\frac{4}{\ln(2)}W_n\left(\frac{1}{4}\ln(2)\right),\ -\frac{4}{\ln(2)}W_n\left(-\frac{1}{4}\ln(2)i\right)$$